# Connect to MS SQL Server from PHP on Linux?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, apache

I need to connect to an MS SQL Server database from a PHP script running on a Linux server. I'm looking at using FreeTDS as there is no official MS SQL Server driver for Linux. Is this my best option? Is it ok in a production environment? Are there other options, perhaps ODBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company I work for has been running FreeTDS to connect to SQL 2000 on our production server for almost 6 years now.  There's a couple of issues with special character encoding, but overall it works well.

Comment: Thanks, now if only I could get the connection working :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the best free option. I've used it with Qt (C++).

You can use it with unixODBC.

If you can pay it you could use the driver from [easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/)

Comment: Thanks, now if only I could get the connection working :)