# PHP 5.4 and MsSQL on XAMPP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, xampp

I'm trying to run `mssql` driver for PHP, but something goes wrong.
I managed to get the right drivers for mssql, then added the extensions in php.ini, but PHP is still running `"--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"`.
I'm running PHP 5.4 under Apache 2.2 on Windows XP SP3.
How to start the mssql drivers?

Comment: Please go through [How to get MS SQL work with PHP 5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3) and report back. Also make sure you are editing the right php.ini (listed in phpinfo) and don't forget to restart the server afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: This was done. `extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll` apache starts PHP normal, no errors, no warnings and without mssql as phpinfo says.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem, for me I needed to use a different version of the driver.

I was using:

extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll

Which gave me the following error in PHP:

[28-Nov-2013 10:58:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: sqlsrv: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API

**The solution:**

extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

Download from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199324/1847383. If you use PHP as an Apache module, use the thread safe version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a great tutorial and explanation on this website:

http://bendustries.co/wp/setting-up-xampp-to-work-with-mssql/

All you need to do is download from here :
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

two files called:

1. **php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll**
2. **php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll**

And place then inside the `php\ext` folder.
Then you need to add those two lines under **"Dynamic Extensions"**

> extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
>
> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll

Save your php.ini file and restart apache, This process worked for me on win7 after I tried several other methods !