# How to enable php_mssql.dll extension in xampp 1.8.x

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp

I'm using `xampp-win32-1.8.3-1-VC11-installer` and i enabled `php_mssql.dll` extension in `php.ini` by remove `;`

I copy `php_mssql.dll` to `xampp\php\ext` 

and `ntwdblib.dll` to `xampp\apache\bin`

i got 2 files above in old of xampp version.

But when i start my `apache` in xampp then i get

[image]

[image]

How to fix that thanks

Comment: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=51070&p=196711&hilit=sqlsrv

Answer (score 2):

It announced from php website `http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php`

> These functions allow you to access MS SQL Server database.
>
> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.
>
> SQLSRV, an alternative extension for MS SQL connectivity is available from Microsoft: `» http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.`

Since XAMPP 1.8.0 its used PHP 5.4.4 and *php_mssql.dll* extension is not available anymore on windows with PHP 5.3 or later.
So you can't use this library to your new XAMPP although you get it from your old XAMPP.
You must use alternative extension to connect to MS SQL Server database like SQLSRV.

See also ::

- `http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php`
- `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3`

Your php version from XAMPP 1.8.3 is PHP 5.5.15, so you must use "*php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll*" or "*php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll*". Those files can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098`.

Note :: see also the information on *Details* section to help you choose file that you must download

This link about documentation to code with sqlsrv library
`http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php`

Answer (score 0):

Windows PHP extensions are neither forward nor backward compatible between second-level PHP versions. That means you cannot use a PHP 5.3 extension in PHP 5.4 and vice-versa.

As you're running XAMPP 1.8.3 and this is one of the first PHP bundles with the VC11-PHP5.5 builds you'll have to find a VC11-PHP5.5 compatible extension somewhere else.
I've just checked another WAMP bundle called EasyPHP, but they don't ship the MS SQL extension with their VC11-PHP5.5 bundle either.

I can't help with finding a compatible extension, though.

You could also build the extension yourself if that is an option for you.