# PHP + MSSQL + IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I'am hosting my page on IIS | Windows Server 2012
I have : SQL Server 2012

The thing is I'am getting this error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\shop\inc\functions.php on line 17
```

code :

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

if(stristr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], "functions.php"))
header("Location: ../");

session_start();

if (!$enable_shop)
die("<p style='text-align: center; color: #FF0000; padding-top: 30%; font-weight: bold'>The shop is currently unavailable.<br/>Please try again later.</p>");

$mssql_con = mssql_connect($mssql_server, $mssql_username, $mssql_password); //Attempt         connection to MSSQL server using above server location.
if (!$mssql_con)
die("Cannot connect to MSSQL Server."); //die, stating it could not connect.
?>
```

SQL Informations are fine etc ... But I think that PHP can't login MSSQL for some reasons .
Thank you , I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

"This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later."
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mssql.php

Comment: I just need to Put the .dll on Ext folder . and Enable them on php.ini ?

Comment: What about give a try to the recommended alternative: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx

Comment: You may take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple odbc connection to your server. You have to create an ODBC interface first. In principle, this should also work without a user and password. If defined in interface.

```php
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:dsnName','user','password');`
```