# How to set Max Pool Size in database connection string using PHP and SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a connection string like this:

```
$cs = "server=localhost;database=Test;uid=admin;pwd=123456";
```

normaly, I split the string then connect to database by using this:

```
// $myserver = "localhost"
// $myuser = "admin"
// $mypwd = "123456"
// $mydb = "Test"

//connect to server
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) 
           or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select the database
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
           or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

But today, I need to connect to the database with Max Pool Size in connection string.

```
$cs = "server=localhost;database=Test;uid=admin;pwd=123456;Max Pool Size=100";
```

How can I add "Max Pool Size=100" option while connect to the database? What if there are more option?

Comment: I think the contents of `$cs` is used for a `PDO` style connection, while you are using the `mssql_*` functions.

Comment: thanks you for reply. That string is from C# same application. In C#, I used SqlConnection(cs) and it will connect with all options.

Comment: As told [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7402803/488074) it looks like these `mssql_` functions are not that common anymore. I would suggest using `PDO`. I cannot find any function to adjust the connection settings using `mssql`.