# Make PHP code with MySQL work with MsSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

We have had a project developed by a group of students as part of their masters degree final project. The overall solution turned out to work great, unfortunately it was developed for MySQL database and we are using a MsSQL Server databases.

I have been trying to work out a wait to make it work but I am not really getting anywhere. On the local machine I am running an Apache server with PHP 5.3.29 and Sql Server 2012.

Info from phpinfo();
Apache Version  Apache/2.2.25 (Win32) PHP/5.3.29 
I can't see mention of mssql in the phpinfo() but in PHP.ini I do have the following:

```
[MSSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
mssql.allow_persistent = On

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
mssql.max_links = -1

; Minimum error severity to display.
mssql.min_error_severity = 10

; Minimum message severity to display.
mssql.min_message_severity = 10

; Compatibility mode with old versions of PHP 3.0.
mssql.compatability_mode = Off

; Connect timeout
;mssql.connect_timeout = 5

; Query timeout
;mssql.timeout = 60

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textlimit = 4096

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
;mssql.textsize = 4096

; Limits the number of records in each batch.  0 = all records in one batch.
;mssql.batchsize = 0

; Specify how datetime and datetim4 columns are returned
; On => Returns data converted to SQL server settings
; Off => Returns values as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
;mssql.datetimeconvert = On

; Use NT authentication when connecting to the server
mssql.secure_connection = On

; Specify max number of processes. -1 = library default
; msdlib defaults to 25
; FreeTDS defaults to 4096
;mssql.max_procs = -1

; Specify client character set.
; If empty or not set the client charset from freetds.conf is used
; This is only used when compiled with FreeTDS
;mssql.charset = "ISO-8859-1"
```

I have tried the following: 
dbconnect.php

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "sa123";
$myDB = "st"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

die();  
  $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

I am first trying to get the system to even allow me to login, so the login.php code is as follows. I have change the queries to mssql:

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start(); // Starting Session
require("includes/db_connect.php");
$hint = "";
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
/*=============================================================
                    SQL INJECTION PREVENTION
===============================================================*/
$PRElist = array();
$PREsql = "SELECT Username, Password FROM tblUsers ;";
$PREresult = mssql_query($PREsql);
//if (mysqli_num_rows($PREresult)>0) 
if (1 == 1){
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($PREresult)) {
        $PRElist[]= strtolower($row['Username']);
        $PRElist[strtolower($row['Username'])]=$row['Password'];
    }
}//to prevent sql injection
//=======================START LOOKING UP THE USER==================
if ((in_array(strtolower($username), $PRElist))&&($PRElist[strtolower($username)]==$password)) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT UserId, Username, Password FROM tblUsers where Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
        $result = mssql_query($sql);
        $numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
        if ($numRows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $hint="";                   //initialize the hint string.. 
                if (strtolower($username)==strtolower($row["Username"])){
                    $userID= $row["UserId"];
                    $sql = "SELECT GroupId FROM tblUserGroups where UserId='$userID'";
                    $result = mssql_query($sql);
                    $numRows1 = mssql_num_rows($result); 
                    if ($numRows1 > 0) {
                        // output data of each row
                        while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            switch ($row["GroupId"]) {
                                case '1':
                                        header("location: home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                                        $hint="<span style='color:green'> This username is registered </span>";
                                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                                        $_SESSION['login_pass']=$password; // Initializing Session# code...
                                        $_SESSION['userID']=$userID; // Initializing Session# code...
                                    break;
                                case '2':
                                        header("location: Team_Home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                                        $hint="<span style='color:green'> This username is registered </span>";
                                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                                        $_SESSION['login_pass']=$password; // Initializing Session# code...
                                        $_SESSION['userID']=$userID; // Initializing Session# code...
                                    break;
                                case '3':
                                        header("location: Staff_Home.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                                        $hint="<span style='color:green'> This username is registered </span>";
                                        $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
                                        $_SESSION['login_pass']=$password; // Initializing Session# code...
                                        $_SESSION['userID']=$userID; // Initializing Session# code...
                                    break;
                                default:
                                        $hint="<span style='color:red'>Not registered...</span>";
                                        header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    $hint="<span style='color:red'>Not registered...</span>";
                    header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page

                }
            }
        } 
    }
    else{
        header("location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        $hint="<span style='color:red'>Not registered...</span>";
    }
    echo $hint;
    mssql_close($conn);
```

I am unable to really see what is happening as when I try to login I just get a white screen with no information or errors in the console.

Comment: If u get a white screen that means you have an syntax error in youre php code

Comment: did you try with error_reporting(E_ALL); ?

Comment: I tried error_reporting and still nothing appears

Comment: This code is very unsafe, those "master students" truly need to learn some aspects of security. This script is vulnerable for SQL injections. Further more your php version is old. Can you add some information from yout phpinfo();

Comment: They have some code for SQL Injection prevention at the start of the file, I just didn't include it in the post. Do you want the full phpinfo(); result or what information are you looking for?

Comment: Please show us more of you're code, by looking now I cant see you have database connection included.

Comment: mssql / pdo extensions + version :)

Comment: Check `php.ini` look for line: `;extension=php_mssql.dll` and if it begins with `;` remove it leave only `extension=php_mssql.dll`, restart everything and check does it work..

Comment: I have added more code and info from phpinfo. In fact I just checked the php.ini and I can't see any mention of mssql.dll, that could be the problem I guess? Does adding the extension=php_mssql.dll will help solve the problem or do I need to reinstall PHP?

Comment: As a recommendation: while you are at a point where you need to change database -- implement your new code using a database abstraction layer such as Propel @ http://propelorm.org/ or Doctrine @ http://www.doctrine-project.org/

As such, your project with be free of database dependency.

Comment: @ArtleMaks - take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3

Comment: the sql injection prevention doesn't really work ;) but's fine for small apps. ¨I could create a username like something `MyName" OR username ="Someoneelse"` ;).  You should add the `extension=php_mssql.dll` to the php.ini it's not there by default @see http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Comment: To be honest, the application will only be used in house so I would consider it to be fairly small. I have tried adding that line to php.ini but I have noticed that this dll is not even in the ext folder of PHP installation.

Comment: I think it's not there because of the older php version. You can find how to install it here on stackoverflow and on the microsoft website

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-to-get-mssql-work-with-php-5-3  

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: I have to agree the PHP version is quite outdated. I think I will try to upgrade to PHP 7 and use the Microsoft driver as this is the  only possible work around that I can see right now. Thanks for all the input! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "sa123";
$myDB = "st"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

die();   // whats this for? it can cause white screen.**



$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

Comment: even if it triggered `die()` he would at least see the message and not a white screen.

Comment: Ooops, that was just some debugging I was doing! Same result without the die(); though

Comment: @Rushikumar what message would you see if you set `die()` at the very begin of your code ?

Comment: @Ultrazz008 You are referring to this, right? `$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");`

Comment: No, the line after that.. It's `die();` alone.

Comment: But it's not problem, he used it for debuging and forgot to remove it.., but first i thought after mssql extension missing that line caused the white screen...

Comment: Ahhh... my misunderstanding!

Comment: Please edit your answer so I can retract my down vote