# Undefined function mssql_connect() Codeigniter 3.0 + Azure Database + 000webhost + PHP 5.6

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, azure-sql-database, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0 on 000webhost (PHP 5.6) and trying to connect to a database on microsoft azure.

I have the following configuration for my database.php file:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'xxxx.database.windows.net',
    'port' => '1433',
    'username' => 'abcd',
    'password' => '*****',
    'database' => 'mydb',
    'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I'm getting the following error:
[image]

I tried changing the dbdriver to sqlsrv. However, I get the same error except now it complains that sqlsrv_connect() is undefined.

PHP info is given below:
[PHP INFO OUTPUT](https://jsfiddle.net/h6ea0c83/)

Comment: mssql extension is not enabled , enable it then check

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy Can you please tell me how to enable mssql extension? I'm using 000webhost free account. I may not have access to PHP installation, etc.

Comment: it will be in php.ini look for php_mssql.dll for more details check beow link http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402713/how-do-i-get-the-sqlsrv-extension-to-work-with-php-since-mssql-is-deprecated

Comment: to which database you are connecting mssql or mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,
The setting in application\config\database.php should be like:

```
'hostname' => '<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433',
'username' => '<username>',
'password' => '<password>',
'database' => '<database>',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
```

Azure doesn't install php_mssql.dll automatically,but it installs php_sqlsrv.dll
So tyr with above.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Now it gives the error sqlsrv_connect() is undefined. I have mentioned this in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this as per your [phpinfo](https://jsfiddle.net/h6ea0c83/) mysqli is installed

```
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
```