# Cannot connect to Microsoft SQLServer 2012 with php 5.3.3

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, freetds

My php file need to access Microsoft SQL Server 2012. So when I try to connect and query using `sqlsrv_query()` I got no error. But I don't get any value return or working.

According to my research, The Microsoft SQL Server Driver only works for 32 bit linux.

Is there any other way, I can make it work in my current setup?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507479/connect-to-ms-sql-server-from-php-on-linux

Comment: There's no problem with the 64 bit version of the MSSQL Server. The respective PHP functions  are called `mssql_something()` . Check http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php . Your PHP needs to be compiled with mssql support.

Answer (score 0):

@Tun Tun,

The Microsoft SQL Server for PHP supports 64bit Linux. Here is a tutorial that helps you get started.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2016/10/10/getting-started-with-php-7-sql-server-and-azure-sql-database-on-linux-ubuntu-with-apache/